# Any Future Plans for Multiline Java String

Tags: java, string, multiline

In the spirit of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886966/java-string-declaration-occupying-multiple-lines

will there be any plans in any future version of Java to allow string continuation in the java scource?

```
String haveUeverSeenLorem =
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \
  consectetur adipisicing elit, \
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
```

Either one way or another, e.g. like the above example.

Comment: A heredoc syntax would be better.  I doubt either is coming any time soon!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems very unlikely. They didn't make the cut for Java 7, as noted in the answer to [Java 7 - Multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581338/java-7-multiline-strings)

Comment: Unlikely - meaning they will not be considering it seriously at all  anytime in the future? Even after gosling has left?

Comment: Proposed and rejected. According to assylias' answer, it happened again in Java 8. As far as I know, no one said never. As far as I know "we will never seriously consider this". Simply, relative to other things they (and I don't know who they are because I don't understand the JCP) decided not to do it so far. I only add "unlikely" because all things being equal I find that a proposal that is repeatedly rejected is likely to continue to be rejected for the same reasons in the future. That's just my opinion, though.

Answer (score 10):

It was proposed for [inclusion in Java 7](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000087.html) but was rejected.

[It was proposed again for Java 8](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2011-August/thread.html#3306) but did not make it to the final version.

[Java 9's JEP 213: Milling Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213) does not include anything regarding multine strings either.

Comment: What's the reason behind this decision? I just don't get it: what are they worried about?

Answer (score 4):

**Update January 2018:**

Have a look at [JEP 326: Raw String Literals](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326).

The planned syntax will be:

```
String haveUeverSeenLorem = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`;
```

Maybe it will be integrated in the next version of Java (Java 11 in September 2018 would be great).

Answer (score 1):

**Update April 2020**

The [JEP 326: Raw String Literals](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326) was withdrawn and is replaced by

[JEP 368: Text Blocks (Second Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/368).

This feature is released as a preview language feature in **Java 14**.

The supported syntax is:

```
String json = """
              {
                 "id": 10,
                 "name": "Joe",
                 "birthday": "1970-01-01"
              }
              """;
```

`"""` (fat delimiters) are used as delimiters for multiline strings.