# Java annotation utility for multiline text

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, multiline

WRT [Any Future Plans for Multiline Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659225/any-future-plans-for-multiline-java-string).

How difficult is it to write a utility that does the following?

```
@AllYouCanEatText(return="query")
private String getQuery(String empid, String[] columns) {
  String query;
  /*
  SELECT ${columns}
  FROM Employees
  WHERE empid = ${empid}
  ;
  */
  return query;
};
```

Of course, before I jump in front of the barrel, I should have asked - Is such a utility already available? If so, where?

The issue at hand is actually - how do I read the comments section in reflection during compile time. As an indication of my (dismal) level of familiarity with Reflection and annotation processing - the last time I used reflection was run-time to read methods. Is compile-time reflection possible?

Is anyone interested in sharing a google code project with me to do this? May be there is already an apache project afoot?

Comment: Why would anyone vote this question down?

Comment: This underscores why my question needed to be voted down for mixing up the two. - At compile time = Annotation Processors. Whereas, run-time = reflection. Thanks for prompting me thro the down vote.

Comment: That is *not* justification for downvoting. It is a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this a while ago, never used it myself, but I think its what you are looking for http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/12/java-multiline-string.html