# Android StringBuilder vs String Concatenation

Tags: android, string, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

I was reading this documentation page, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.

The section here caught my eye:

> Tip: Don't forget that when you make a call like
>
> `Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);`
>
> that when you're building the string to pass into Log.d, the compiler
>   uses a StringBuilder and at least three allocations occur: the
>   StringBuilder itself, the buffer, and the String object.
>   Realistically, there is also another buffer allocation and copy, and
>   even more pressure on the gc. That means that if your log message is
>   filtered out, you might be doing significant work and incurring
>   significant overhead.

This implies that the Android compiler is taking string concatenations (+) and converting them into StringBuilder and append statements.

**Is my assumption correct or is it still better to use StringBuilder manually instead of string concatenation?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation in Java - when to use +, StringBuilder and concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler does exactly what you suggest is implied. You can print the bytecodes of the generated .class file (using `javap -c`) and see the calls to construct and use a `StringBuilder`.

However, it's generally worth doing it manually when the string concatenations are spread over several lines of code. The compiler usually allocates a separate `StringBuilder` for every String-valued expression involving `+`.

Comment: @JeremyEdwards - Heh. I've said that about a lot of things. :)

Comment: **"it's generally worth doing it manually when the string concatenations are spread over several lines of code"** - I just wanted to emphasize what @TedHopp said so it isn't lost. I was concatenating a 250 character string over about 10 lines and the cpu time on App Engine was 350 msec. When I replaced this with a single StringBuilder the time was down to 50 msec, other things unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Ted Hopp's answer is good, but it took reading it a few times to understand. Here is a rephrased answer that is hopefully more clear.

String concatenation (ie, using `+`, as in `String myString = "Hello " + "World";`) uses a `StringBuilder` in the background along with other allocations. Thus, for anything other than a simple one-time concatenation, it would be better to use a `StringBuilder` yourself.

For example,

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
myString.append("Hello ");
myString.append("to ");
myString.append("everyone ");
myString.append("in ");
myString.append("the ");
myString.append("world!");
```

is better than

```
String myString = "Hello " + "to " + "everyone " + "in " + "the " + "world!";
```

Comment: But if my string is just '"index=" + i', what's the best way? (For performance)

Comment: @GMX, That's a good question and I think it would depend on the context. If this is only being called infrequently, then using `"index=" + i` is much more readable than using a `StringBuilder`. However, if it is being called 1000 times inside of a loop and performance is an issue, then maybe some sort of `StringBuilder` option would be better. The main point of the accepted answer, though, was that when it takes multiple lines of code to build a string, then definitely use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: To be precise: In the StringBuilder version, you will have to add myString.toString() to get a proper String