# Printing Circular List

Tags: java, data-structures, circular-list

I'm doing my assignment which is to create a Circular List, I believe that my methods are working properly, except for my print method.

```
    public String print() {
        String str = "";
        Node curr = first;

        for(int i = 0; i < getSize(); curr = curr.getNext(), i++) {
            str += curr.getData();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

I test it with the numbers: {1,2,3,4,5}, and when I call my print method I get 15432 as a result. Does any one know what could be wrong with this, apparently I'm not seeing it. Also if you need more code, let me know.

EDIT: After some comments I realize it's not my print method, here are my add() and getData() methods:

```
    public void add(int value) {
        if(first == null) {
            first = new Node(value, null);
            first.setNext(first);
        } else {
            Node newNode = new Node(value, first.getNext());
            first.setNext(newNode);
        }
        System.out.println("Added: " + value);
        size++;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return first.getData();
    }
```

EDIT 2: The constructor;

```
class CircularList {
    private Node first;
    private int size;

    public CircularList() {
        first = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    ....
```

Comment: What did you discover when you tried debugging this?

Comment: Nothing apparently wrong here. Maybe your `add` method is adding items in the wrong order. Is this a doubly linked list?

Comment: can we have the getNext() implementation and the constructor/add element methods?

Comment: `curr.getNext()` - Are you sure this is doing what it is supposed to do? From what you describe, `curr.getNext()` appears to function as a `curr.getPrev()`

Comment: Offtopic: Don't use += with Strings. Use StringBuilder.

Comment: It looks like you have your next a previous pointers backwards. If so, the bug would either be in the `add()` method or in `getNext()`

Comment: I'm rather sure your problem isn't in the above code snippet

Comment: I just updated the post to include the add() and getData() methods, I will change my print method to use String Builder, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you write a simple unit test which adds one element at a time and check it adds them in the order you expect.  When you discover the simplest case which doesn't do what you expect, I suggest stepping through your code in your debugger so you understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `add` method: it appears that the method adds the item as the number two in the list, rather than adding it to its end. This does not apply to the initial entry, because the head and the tail are the same for it.

To fix this problem, keep the `Node last` element in the `CircularList`, and do the insertion at the `last`, not at the `first` element. This makes deletion of the last element a little harder to manage, but the speedup that you gain is worth it.

If you would like to surprise your teacher, you can use a "magic trick":

```
public void add(int value) {
    if(first == null) {
        first = new Node(value, null);
        first.setNext(first);
    } else {
        // Remember the current first
        Node oldFirst = first;
        // Make a copy of the first node the "new first"
        first = new Node(first.getValue(), first.getNext());
        // Copy the new value into the "old first",
        // and make its next point to the "new first"
        oldFirst.setValue(value);
        oldFirst.setNext(first);
    }
    System.out.println("Added: " + value);
    size++;
}
```

Make sure that you fully understand this trick. Draw it on a piece of paper to understand it better. Your teacher may ask you about this, because it's not very common.

As far as the printing goes, do not use `+=`, use `StringBuilder` instead. You can also avoid the counter by observing that your printing should end when the `curr` reaches `first` again:

```
public String print() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    Node curr = first;
    while (true) {
        str.append(curr.getData());
        curr = curr.getNext();
        if (curr == first) break;
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, drawing out a diagram definitely helped. Is there a reason as to use StringBuilder as opposed to +=?

Comment: @user1327636 The reason to avoid `+=` in a loop is that otherwise each iteration creates a new instance of `String` which gets thrown away. If you are printing `{1,2,3,4}`, then the strings `"1"`, `"1,2"`, and `"1,2,3"` will be created temporarily, and then thrown away (recall that Java strings are immutable, so `+=` makes a new object). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7817989/335858) is a link to an answer discussing the problem at some length.

Comment: In your add method should we add first = oldfirst at the end in the else condition .... because its a class variable.....

Comment: @bapusethi No, absolutely not. You seem to have misunderstood the approach. I do not blame you, it's not trivial. Please try this out with paper and pencil to see how this works. P.S. Your edit was incorrect, I rejected it.