# Difference between Initializing string with new and " "

Tags: java, string

Which one is correct and why:

```
String dynamic = new String();
dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";

Or

String dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

Please suggest what is the difference in above 2 initilizaton of String.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between string object and string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

Comment: Not actually a duplicate of that, as in this case the constructed String is instantly discarded.

Answer (score 5):

```
String dynamic = new String();   //created an String object
dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'"; //overriding reference with new value
```

Since string is immutable and now `dynamic`  will store in common pool.

And

```
String dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

Is again a literal and stores in common pool.

So , `String` can be created by directly assigning a `String` literal which is shared in a **common pool.**

It is uncommon and not recommended to use the **new** operator to construct a `String` object in the **heap**.

So the  line

```
String dynamic = new String();
```

Is redundant and allocating unnecessary memory in heap.

**Don't do that.**

Learn what happens in both the cases, then you come to know.

- [How can a string be initialized using " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

And finally, do not use much concatenation's with "+", cannot do much harm in lesser amount of concatenations. If you are dealing with larger amount prefer to use `StringBuilder` with **append** method.

- [String concatenation in Java - when to use +, StringBuilder and concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat)

Comment: `Since string is immutable and now dynamic will store in common pool.`. that stement is true. Since OP initializing that as literal, it stores in common pool :check once here .A little demo. https://ideone.com/4fmg7k

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
String str = new String();
```

creates a new String object on the heap. When you do afterwards:

```
str = "Hello, String Pool";
```

You simply overwrite the reference to the first object with another reference. Thus, the first object is lost. Keep this in mind: **Strings are immutable**.

Answer (score 1):

As we know that String class is  immutable so ,
**`String str="Hello String";`**
is the best way of using String class so we can avoid memory wastage.When string with the same value created.

Answer (score 1):

**String str = new String();** // as there is new operator so you are creating an object of string. This is going to create extra space in memory. So wastage of memory and redundant.Its not advisable to use it until you are not creating some complex object.

But **String str ="qwerty"** means that u are assigning it to str. As bot are stored in common pool. So its better to use this notation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do in this way

```
String dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";

String dynamic  = new String();// DON'T DO THIS!
dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

The statement creates a new String instance each time it is executed, and none of those object creations is necessary. The argument to the String constructor (" where id='" + unitId + "'") is itself a String instance, functionally identical to all of the objects created by the constructor. If this usage occurs in a loop or in a frequently invoked method, millions of String instances can be created needlessly. The improved version is simply the following:

```
String dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

Comment: Please tell the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

```
String dynamic = new String();
dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

creates a binding to an empty string, and then dumps it completely by re-initializing it.

```
String dynamic = " where id='" + unitId + "'";
```

creates the binding and leaves it.

The first one is unnecessary. Just go with the direct string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("where id='");
stringBuilder.append(unitId);
stringBuilder.append("'");

String dynamic = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Ahhh..You completely missed the question.

Comment: FYI: If you use simple `+=` on Strings, it gets compiled into this StringBuilder approach.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ thanks.. Both way are not good for string concatenation.

Comment: @Prabhakaran OP showed a typical example. He wants to know which is the better way either ""  or with new ?? concatenation is not an issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below will be good

```
String str; // Just declares the variable and the default will be null. This can be done in global scope or outer scope

str = "where id" + unitID + "'"; // Initializing string with value when needed. This will be done in the inner scope.
```

If declaration and initialization done in a line where the initialization contains dynamic text (unitID in your case) you can't do it globally. If Scope of the variable is not an issue then u may go ahead. Cheers!!