# Java Strings Output confusion

Tags: java, string

I have been asked this question in an interview, I said both would return false.
but when I crossed checked it 
 one was true other was false

can anyone explain it?

```
        String s1 = "H";
        String s2 = "e";
        String s3 = s1+s2;
        String s4 = "He";
        System.out.println(s3 == s4);//false

        String s5="h";
        String s6="h";
        System.out.println(s5 == s6);//true
```

Comment: Compare `String` using `.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: @Salah  OP wants know the reason for that.

Comment: The second one is true because Java employs a technique called [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ its just a note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s3 = s1+s2;
```

That string realized at **run time** and created a reference of that in heap.
when we concat strings with (+) operator JVM returns new `StringBuilder(string...).toString()`

Where as in second case

```
String s5="h";
String s6="h";
```

s5 and s6 both are resolved at **compile time**  and pointing to same reference((*Constant pool*)).

Helpful :https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419194/1927832

Comment: why does it reference same memory location in case of 2 one???can you explain brief about string pool what here you are referring to constant pool

Comment: Ratika, Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410

Answer (score 0):

String comparision needs to be done using

string.equals function == compares the references.

s5 == s6 returns true due to "h" being a constant

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is that a string pool is being used, as strings are often re-used they are sometimes allocated the same piece of memory. So, assigning `s5` and `s6` the same value on initialization will allocate them the same address, whereas assigning a string to be the concatenation of two other strings will always generate a new address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.equals(String other)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.

The function checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. Note that string constants are usually "interned" such that two constants with the same value can actually be compared with `==`, but it's better not to rely on that.

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

The "==" operator returns true if the object addresses are the same. At compile time all identical **literal** Strings are reduced to the same String object.  Therefore:

```
String s1 = "A";
String s2 = "A"; // s1 == s2: points to the same address as s1

String s3 = "AA"
String s4 = s1+s2; // s3 != s4: the literal "AA" is a different object
```

String.equals() compares the String values, not the addresses.

Answer (score -1):

you can't use `==` on strings, you need to use the `String.equals` function. 
you can use it like that:

```
        String s1 = "H";
        String s2 = "e";
        String s3 = s1+s2;
        String s4 = "He";
        System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));//false

        String s5="h";
        String s6="h";
        System.out.println(s5.equals(s6));//true
```