# Append Strings - Performance issue - Java 6

Tags: java, string, performance, append, stringbuilder

I need to repeatedly append strings (for about 50 times), which is a substring of another StringBuilder. 
I need to do this for around 30k inputs.
It takes me a time of around 6 minutes.

```
 StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(10000);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(10000);
```

//for loop till end of file which reads strings into variable 'input'

```
{
output.append(input.substring(1, 8));
output.append(input.substring(33, 45));
output.append(input.substring(20, 25)); // and so on
}
```

This took around 6 minutes.

So, i tried something like

```
{


 output.append(input.substring(1, 8) + output.append(input.substring(33, 45) + output.append(input.substring20, 25) + .. // and so on );
```

}

This, has also taking the same time. I know both of these are same.

But, eventhough I use a StringBuilder, why still I have performance lag? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I referred: [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java?rq=1)
and  [String concatenation in Java - when to use +, StringBuilder and concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat?lq=1) and some more. 
Most of them suggest to use a StringBuilder.

Comment: I suggest monitoring GC activity while your loop is in progress. You may be running into memory limits.

Comment: " I know both of these are same." No they're not. Your second code converts `output` to a string on each iteration, and uses string concatenation. You definitely don't want to do that.

Comment: Maybe this is your issue: "for loop till end of file which reads strings into variable 'input' "? Show us how you set up the reader and how you are reading.

Comment: There is no way that appending 50 small substrings, 50K times take much more than a few seconds.  If it is taking longer it is more likely to be doing work somewhere you haven't mentioned.  I suggest you profile your application.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : Actually I read them from queue.. not from a file.. so, I read till the queue size is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the performance issue is elsewhere as this shouldn't take more than a second.  I suggest you profile your application to determine where it is actually spending it's processing time.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
char[] chars = new char[500];
Arrays.fill(chars, '.');
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    String input = new String(chars);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        output.append(input, j * 10, j * 10 + 9);
    }
    String out = output.toString();
}
System.out.println("Took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1e3 + " seconds");
```

prints for 50 substrings of 30,000 strings

```
Took: 0.058 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely avoid creating so many objects using the overload of `append` which allows you to specify a subsequence:

```
for (...)
{
    output.append(input, 1, 8);
    output.append(input, 33, 45);
    output.append(input, 20, 25);
}
```

That may or may not help you. The string concatenation in your second example should definitely be avoided - I'm surprised that isn't making a *huge* difference... that suggests it may well not be the appending that's taking the time, but whatever's reading the input.

To test that, you should possibly try an *empty* `for` loop, so that you're still reading all the same input, but not appending to `output` at all.

Comment: The short-lived strings will just increase minor GC frequency. The chance that this is the problem is vanishingly small, especially given the small size of individual substrings.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agreed. Basically we really can't tell where the time is going here - hence my suggestion of just cycling through the inputs.