# Splitting main method arguments ignoring whitespace

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm having main method arguments separated by commas and some of the values might have white spaces also, I have to split only comma separated values ignoring whitespaces.

eg: abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst

I have tried using `split(",")` but it's giving me 4 values instead of 3 as the last element should be treated as one element.

Here's my code:

```
public class ArgCheck {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String x = Arrays.toString(args);
        System.out.println(x);
        String [] y = x.split(",");
        System.out.println(y.length);
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally using `"abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst".split(",")`.  Can you tell us more about your setup?

Comment: Show us your exact code.. Can't reproduce this

Comment: @KranthiSama : Do you need the `mnop qrst` as a single parameter?

Comment: Java can do nothing for you here; what you need to do is quote arguments correctly in your command interpreter.

Comment: @KranthiSama : Did you try my answer?

Comment: If you are passing `abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst` as your `args` to your main methods then you can check the values and length of `args`. Length will be 2 and values will be `abcdef,xyzert,mnop` & `qrst`.

Comment: From the java docs for the `Arrays.toString` method: *Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space)* Thus, a comma is added between "mnop" and "qrst", producing 4 results. To solve this, find an alternative to `Arrays.toString()` for argument concatenation or change input to `abcdef,xyzert,"mnop qrst"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join all the elements of the `args` first and then split it.
Like this:

```
String str = "";
for (String eachArg : args) {
    str += eachArg + " ";
}
System.out.println (str.split(",").length);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to loose white space. white space should not be ignored. @Sweeper

Comment: Answer edited. Now you can just concatenate a " " to the string and you can also check whether it is the last argument and if it is then don't add the space. @Kranthi Sama

Comment: It is generally not optimal to concatenate Strings using `+` *inside a loop*. For each iteration a new `StringBuilder` is created, unnecessarily creating intermediate Strings. Better to use `StringBuilder` from the get go. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat and

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst` as your `args` to your main methods then you can check the values and length of args. Length will be `2` and values will be `abcdef,xyzert,mnop` & `qrst`.

---

To achieve what you want you can change your input in command line to **`abcdef,xyzert,"mnop qrst"`**. You need to use `""` to identify it as **one word**.

And if you don't know what input will be as in which field will have space in between then you can use general rule

to wrap all your words in `""` and pass it to main method like

**`"abcdef","xyzert","mnop qrst"`**

**or** wrap entire line in `""` and then pass it to main method like

**`"abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst"`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this once, receive the variable `string` as your command-line argument.

```
String string = "abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst";
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1]; 
String part3 = parts[2];
System.out.println(part1+"\n"+part2+"\n"+part3);
```

If you need `n` number of values in that case simply use a `loop`

```
for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
    System.out.println(parts[i]);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First try removing the white spaces from the String first.

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

got this from [Removing whitespace from strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

After removing the white spaces, you may now use the split method.

Comment: I tried this code snippet 
String foo = "abcdef,xyzert,mnop qrst";  
for(String s : foo.split(",")){
 System.out.println(s);
}
It gave me 3 values instead of 4, [abcdef][xyzert][mnop qrst] respectively