# use for loop how print it separately after two character a string java

Tags: java, string

input 10100011

output 10 10 00 11 two word separately.

```
static String getValue(String x){
    String y = "";
    int getLength = x.length();
    if (getLength % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println("Length : "+getLength/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength/2; i++){

        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: You can use a simple split like this ([demo](https://ideone.com/sON6nq))

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a `StringBuilder`<sup>1</sup> to append the character to the string being built. 
The for loop starts at index 0. In the body of the for loop, it gets the character at index `i` and `i + 1` and appends to the current builder along with a space. On each iteration, `i` gets incremented by two.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
if (getLength % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println("Length : "+getLength/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i += 2){
        builder.append(x.charAt(i))
               .append(x.charAt(i + 1))
               .append(" ");
    }
}
return builder.toString();
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for using a StringBuilder is for performance benefits. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat).

Comment: what is length is odd?

Comment: It returns an empty string ("")

Comment: but don't you think if input is `11001` then it should return `11 00 1`?

Comment: @Kaushal28 It could. But from the question, it seemed the intention is to do this only for string of even length and return an empty string when the length is odd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string operations for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i+=2){
   System.out.print(str.substring(i, i+2) + " ");
}
if(str.length() % 2 != 0)
    System.out.print(str.substring(str.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to print two digits in string separately.

As per **10 10 00 11** this output,

```
static String getValue(String x){
    String y = "";
    int getLength = x.length();

        System.out.println("Length : "+getLength/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength; i++){
            if(i%2 == 1) { // this purpose of this check is to make sure this string index starting from 0.
                System.out.println(y[i]+" ") // whenever second digit comes it will print space as well to show seperation.
            } else {
            System.out.println(y[i])
            }
        }

    return y;
}
```