# String is unable to print when I use charAt()

Tags: java

I want to find the palindrome of a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String s1 = "eye",s2="";
     for(int i = s1.length()-1;i<=0;--i)
     {
          s2 =s2+String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i));

     }
          System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

I expected the output 
eye
eye
but, s2 isn't printing.

Comment: I think your `i<=0` should be `i>=0`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong condition in the for loop. The correct condition should be `i>=0`.

Remember that as long as this condition is true, the for loop will run. Your original condition, `i<=0` is false at the very beginning, when `i` is 2, so the for loop never starts.

A less important problem is that you should not concatenate strings in a for loop, and should use a `StringBuilder` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat).