# Error in verifying suffixes of a word in Java

Tags: java, string

The task is to create a function that takes two strings as arguments and returns true if the second string is a suffix of the first. My code worked for all test cases except two. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Examples:

> isSuffix("vocation", "-logy") ➞ false
>
> isSuffix("arachnophobia", "-phobia") ➞ true

My code:

```
    public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    String suff = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < suffix.length(); i++)    suff += "" + suffix.charAt(i);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < suff.length(); i++){
        if(!(word.charAt(suff.length()-1-i) == suff.charAt(suff.length()-1-i))) return false;
    }
    
    return true;        
}
```

The test cases I'm failing:

```
@Test
public void test5() {
    assertThat(Program.isSuffix("arachnophobia", "-phobia"), is(true));
}

@Test
public void test6() {
    assertThat(Program.isSuffix("rhinoplasty", "-plasty"), is(true));
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the hyphen in the suffix paramter?

Comment: @pczeus It is given in the question itself. Can't help it.

Comment: Does suffix always start with `-`? If yes then check if `word.endsWith(sufix.substring(1))`.

Comment: @azro I'm so sorry, I totally moved on without remembering to accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to remove the hypen, just use `substring`, doing string concatenation in loop is not a good idea , giving `String suff = suffix.substring(1)`

Then, you're using `stuff.length` instead of `word.length()`, giving in fact

```
public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    String suff = suffix.substring(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < suff.length(); i++) {
        if (!(word.charAt(word.length() - 1 - i) == suff.charAt(suff.length() - 1 - i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

And in fact you could just `substring` from `word` with the same length of the suffix and check if they are equals

```
public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    String suff = suffix.substring(1);
    String wordSuffix = word.substring(word.length() - suff.length());
    return suff.equals(wordSuffix);
}
```

And even better using `.endsWith`, but this is assuming you can use the builtin methods

```
public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    return word.endsWith(suffix.substring(1));
}
```

Also this code assumes that both are non null, and there always is the hyphen

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask why doing string concatenation in a loop is not a good idea?

Comment: @SthitaprajnaMishra It creates a new string each time, first a StringBuilder would be better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat if really needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.endsWith()` and `String.substring()` to solve the problem easily, with minimal code (after included validation of course):

```
public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    if(word == null || suffix == null) return false;
    if(suffix.length() <= 1 || !suffix.startsWith("-")) return false;

    return word.endsWith(suffix.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is rather complicated, as you loop through the letters.

```
public static boolean isSuffix(String word, String suffix) {
    // Remove first character
    String suff = suffix.substring(1);
    // Get Suffix from word
    String wordEnding = word.substring(word.length()-suffix.legnth());

    // Compare
    if(wordEnding.compareTo(suff)==0){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't do `wordEnding.compareTo(suff)==0` this is just `.equals()` ;)

Comment: You are right. I haven't written Java in a long time ;)

Answer (score 0):

`word.charAt(suff.length()-1-i)` should be `word.charAt(word.length()-1-i)`

I just realized this.