# I want to show output from for loop in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have an ArrayList and i want to loop through the ArrayList and print the items in the arraylist to JOptionPane.showInput dialogue. But how can i use a looping structure in JOptionPane? The code below shows multiple JOptionPane windows and obiously it will because it is in a loop. Can anyone modify it to show only one JOptionPane window and output all messages in one window.

```
public void getItemList(){
          for (int i=0; i<this.cartItems.size(); i++){
           JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1) + "." +
                    this.cartItems.get(i).getName(););
        }
            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append all the elements of `cartItems` into a `StringBuilder` and show the `JOptionPane` with the `StringBuilder` only once after the loop is terminated.

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    List<String> cartItems = List.of("Tomato", "Potato", "Onion", "Cabbage");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        new Main().getItemList();
    }

    public void getItemList() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cartItems.size(); i++) {
            sb.append((i + 1) + "." + this.cartItems.get(i)).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(sb);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The *message* parameter in method `showInputDialog()` can be any subclass of `java.lang.Object`, including a `javax.swing.JList`.

```java
// Assuming 'cartItems' is instance of 'java.util.List'
JList<Object> list = new JList<>(cartItems.toArray());
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(list);
```

Refer to [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 2):

you need to define a string variable and put every values of `ArrayList` in it and then separate each value with "\n" (new line) and after ending of loop display the input dialog:

```
public static void getItemList(){
    String value = "";
    for (int i=0; i<this.cartItems.size(); i++){
        value += (i+1) + "." + this.cartItems.get(i).getName() + "\n";
    }  
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(value);
}
```

Comment: You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` in case of repeated string concatenation within a loop. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/7817951/10819573 for a discussion on this topic.