# How can I traverse through String and process it as required in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am fairly new to Java programming, thus facing issues to handle issues such as this. I am writing a program to check if the string input contains at least 2 odd numbers. As part of the problem which I am solving, it asks me to take input for the number of digits my number will have - but that is irrelevant at this point.

I have attempted to traverse through the string and record the first two found odd numbers in a string and then print it. But it seems to fail and I can't understand why.

NB: If the string input is `12272`, then it should print `17` as these two are the only odd numbers.

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tc = scanner.nextInt();

        while(true){
            String str="";
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            String num = scanner.nextLine();
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
                int extractedDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(num.charAt(i)));
                if(extractedDigit % 2 != 0){
                    cnt++;
                    str += Integer.toString(extractedDigit);
                    if(cnt == 2)break;
                }

            }
            if(cnt == 2) System.out.println(str);
            else System.out.println("-1");

            if(tc == 0)break;
            tc--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "number" is any possible number.  "digit" is any one of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Comment: Yes, I know. I should be more careful when writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn the following things which will in turn also solve your problem:

1. You can replace `Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(num.charAt(i)))` with `num.charAt(i) - '0'` because you can perform arithmetic operations on `char` in the same way you perform on `int` e.g. `'5' - '2'` gives `3`.
2. I recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for repeated string concatenation in a loop because using `String` will create additional as many instances of `String`  as the number of concatenation. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat) to learn more about it. Note that you can append a `char` value directly to a `StringBuilder`.
3. You should make a habit of enclosing the body of a block within `{...}` even if you have a single statement in the body. This will save you from some statement accidentally falling out of scope e.g.

   ```
   if (1 == 2)
       System.out.print("Hello");
       System.out.println("World");

   System.out.println("What's up?");
   ```

will print

```
World
What's up?
```

and not just

```
What's up?
```

4. You do not need to enclose `-1` with double quotes to print `-1`.

Incorporating all these points, you can write the solution as

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String num = scanner.nextLine();
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            int extractedDigit = num.charAt(i) - '0';
            if (extractedDigit % 2 != 0) {
                cnt++;
                str.append(extractedDigit);
                if (cnt == 2) {
                    break;
                }
            }    
        }
        if (cnt == 2) {
            System.out.println(str);
        } else {
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
12272
17
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out hope it will work

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = scanner.nextLine();
        String str = "";

        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            int extractedDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(num.charAt(i)));
            if (extractedDigit % 2 != 0) {
                cnt++;
                str += Integer.toString(extractedDigit);
                if (cnt == 2) break;
            }
        }
        if (cnt == 2) {
            System.out.println(str);
        } else System.out.println("-1");
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. You can also read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I got to this point, but whenever I use this same code in a while loop, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'num' variable is always an empty string. This is because `Scanner.nextInt()` only reads numeric characters, and leaves trailing line separators (it reads line separators *before* the number though). So after you call nextInt(), the next readable character in the scanner is a line separator.

Scanner.nextLine(), as the name suggests, reads until the next line separator. This happens to be the very first character, so it returns an empty string - which contains no odd numbers.

To fix this, use `Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` instead of `nextInt()` if the input text is on separate lines, or call `scanner.nextLine()` before the critical statement to read the empty line.

EDIT: Working code, assuming every input is on a separate line:

```
    int tc = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    
    while(true){
        String str="";
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        String num = scanner.nextLine();
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            int extractedDigit = Integer.parseInt(""+num.charAt(i));
            if(extractedDigit % 2 != 0){
                cnt++;
                str += Integer.toString(extractedDigit);
                if(cnt == 2)break;
            }
            
        }
        if(cnt == 2) System.out.println(str);
        else System.out.println("-1");
        if(tc == 0)break;
        tc--;
    }
```

Comment: This is somewhat confusing for me. I have used `scanner.nextInt()` to get the number of digit for the number I want to check, and `scanner.nextLine()` to read the string input.

Comment: scanner.nextInt() doesn't read the entire line and turns it into an int, it only reads the next int and doesn't care about the rest

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) says nextInt() parses the next 'token'. Tokens are separated by whitespace characters by default, and whitespace characters include space, tabulator and line separators.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not suggesting the traditional approaches. This is to just give you an idea of how functional programming can make your life easier :)

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine(); // Assuming input = "123456"
    Arrays.stream(input.split("")) // returns ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
        .map(Integer::parseInt) // returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        .filter(num -> num % 2 != 0) // Allows elements that pass num % 2 != 0 predicate 
        .forEach(System.out::print); //prints the elements that passed through the filter
```

Now, modifying for fetching the count is very easy,

```
 long oddElementCount = Arrays.stream(input.split("")) // returns ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
        .map(Integer::parseInt) // returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        .filter(num -> num % 2 !=0) // filters all elements that do not satisfy the predicate
        .count(); //prints the count of elements that satisfy the given Predicate (num %2 != 0)
    System.out.println(oddElementCount);
```