# If statement unexpectedly loops infinitely inside for loop

Tags: java

input: "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea?"
expected output: "Who sevil in a elppaenip rednu the sea?" (reverse size 5 and above words)

I think the if statement is the problem but I don't know why it's not working. I tried using the code from the if statement block inside the main method and it works fine.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea?"; 
        System.out.println(spinWords(sentence)); 
    }
    
      public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
        String[] words = sentence.split(" "); 
        int length = words.length; 
        String spinned = ""; 
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String word = words[i];  
            int wlength = word.length(); 
            if (wlength > 4) {  
                String reversed = ""; 
                for (i = wlength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    reversed += "" + word.charAt(i); 
                }
                spinned += reversed + " ";
            } else {
              spinned += word + " "; 
            }
        }
        spinned = spinned.trim(); 
        return spinned; 
      }
}
```

This is my first stack overflow question btw and I don't really know what I'm doing.
I would also love to see better implementations of this code ( for learning purposes ), thanks.

Comment: It is *very* unintuitive to have nested loops, both using `i` as their counter. I would say you almost never want to do that. Change the 2nd nested loop to use a different counter. `for (int j = wlength - 1; j >= 0; j--) {`

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a different counter.

Comment: @Michael agreed. As explanation: The ´i´ in the first for loop should increase by each iteration. Insted every time the second for loop is finished the `i` value is back to 0! So the first for loop has to start from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I forgot to change word.charAt(i) so I got an exception, but it works fine now with the new counter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "if" block with below code. You were using the variable "i" which is used by the first "for" loop. This caused the infinite loop.

```
    if (wlength > 4) {  
        String reversed  = "";
         for(int j = 0; j < wlength; j++) {
             reversed = word.charAt(j) + reversed;
         }
         spinned += reversed + " ";
    } else {
      spinned += word + " "; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is the duplicate use of the local variable `i` as others have pointed out.  Typically you never want a nested loop counter to use the same variable name as the outer loop counter.

There is a reason why `for (int i = wlength - 1; i >= 0; i--)` is a compilation error (with the `int` declaration added).  Instead simply use another variable name:

`for (int j = wlength - 1; j >= 0; j--)`

This will fix the error in the code.  However, since you asked for other implementations I thought I would show another option using `StringBuilder`, which I believe is easier to read:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea?";
    System.out.println(spinWords(sentence));
}

public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (String str : words) {
        if (str.length() >= 5) {
            sb.append(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());
        } else {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

`StringBuilder` is often used when concatenating a `String` inside of a loop, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat#:%7E:text=Repeated%20string%20concatenation%20within%20a,side%20argument%20is%20not%20empty).

Additionally, `StringBuilder` has the `reverse()` method which you can use to reverse individual words instead of using a nested loop.  You then just use `toString` to convert the `StringBuilder` object into a `String`.

Lastly, I used an enhanced for loop of `for (String str : words)` which allows you to loop directly on the `String` values instead of needing to use a loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
      .map(word -> word.length() < 5 ? word : new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/csqqjh).