# Putting an html link inside java code

Tags: java, html

I am new to java coding. I have an application thats can send mails, implemented in Java. I want to put a HTML link inside the mail, but when I put a html link, it shows an error saying ; is missing even though everything is correct.

```
String msgbody = "This is a reminder mail"; 
String link = "<a href="http://abcd.efg.com" target="_blank">http://abcd.efg.com</a>"; 
msgbody = msgbody + link;
```

Is there anything wrong if I use a string like this?

Comment: You cannot use nested quotes. Correct your code to the followng:
`String link = "<a href=\"http://abcd.efg.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://abcd.efg.com</a>";`. Follow the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). Particularly, the section about escape sequences.

Comment: String msgbody = "very good information";
String link = "<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569420/putting-an-html-link-inside-java-code">http://abcd.efg.com</a>";

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape quotes in string literals.

Instead of

```
String link = "<a href="http://abcd.efg.com" target="_blank">http://abcd.efg.com</a>";
```

try

```
String link = "<a href=\"http://abcd.efg.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://abcd.efg.com</a>";
```

For more info see ["Characters"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

> #### Escape Sequences
>
> A character preceded by a backslash (`\`) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java escape sequences:
>
> ...
>
> When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the compiler interprets it accordingly. For example, **if you want to put quotes within quotes** you must use the escape sequence, `\"`, on the interior quotes. To print the sentence
>
> `She said "Hello!" to me.`
>
> you would write
>
> ```
> System.out.println("She said \"Hello!\" to me.");
> ```

Answer (score 3):

you can use escape method as answered above or you can make use of single quotes.as below :

```
String link = "<a href='http://abcd.efg.com' target='_blank'>http://abcd.efg.com</a>";
```

Single quotes just works fine with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

use [multiLine Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155171/2891692) is included in JDK 15:

```
String msgbody = "This is a reminder mail";
String link = """
<a href="http://abcd.efg.com" target="_blank">http://abcd.efg.com</a>""";
msgbody = msgbody + link;
```