# Don't understand \n

Tags: java

Could you help me understand how to get the same result by usint \n?

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance);
System.out.println();
```

I have tried something like

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +\n);
```

Not working. Don't know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You're forgetting the quotes. `"\n"` or `("Balance: " + balance + "\n")`

Comment: [Multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)

Comment: Didn't this throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include "\n" in quotes. The "\" operator is to ignore the next operator, and `n` stands for `new line`. If you just put "n", it will be a string output of "n".

`System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +"\n");` gives you:

```
Balance: *value* 

Next output will be here
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `"\n"` at the end of the string:

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance + "\n");
```

This works because `\n` is a special character that stands for *newline*. It's platform-independent; you won't need to use `\r\n` or anything like that. You can use `\n` anywhere a string is accepted.

However, in this case, I would actually favor the first approach, because it makes it clear what you're trying to do. A call to `println()` is much clearer than a `\n` subtly tacked on at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is the escape sequence for newline character and must be used as a constant of type `char`.
So code will be:

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance + "\n");
```

or

```
System.out.println("Balance: " + balance +'\n');
```

There are other escape chars as \t (tab), \b etc
Loeek [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) for full list and explanation

Comment: "must [be] used as a constant of type char" or in a String; it's not really a `char` then