# Simple way templating multiline strings in java code

Tags: java, templating, multilinestring

I'm often run in to the following situation: I have long multiline strings where properties must be injected - e.g. something like templating. But I don't want to inlcude a complete templating engine (like velocity or freemarker) in my projects.

How can this be done in a simple way:

```java
String title = "Princess";
String name  = "Luna";
String community = "Stackoverflow";

String text =
   "Dear " + title + " " + name + "!\n" +  
   "This is a question to " + community + "-Community\n" + 
   "for simple approach how to code with Java multiline Strings?\n" + 
   "Like this one.\n" + 
   "But it must be simple approach without using of Template-Engine-Frameworks!\n" + 
   "\n" + 
   "Thx for ...";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own small & simply template engine with few lines of code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String title = "Princes";
    String name  = "Luna";
    String community = "Stackoverflow";

    InputStream stream = DemoMailCreater.class.getResourceAsStream("demo.mail");


    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.available()];
    stream.read(buffer);

    String text = new String(buffer);

    text = text.replaceAll("§TITLE§", title);
    text = text.replaceAll("§NAME§", name);
    text = text.replaceAll("§COMMUNITY§", community);

    System.out.println(text);

}
```

and small text file e.g. in the same folder (package) `demo.mail`:

```
Dear §TITLE§ §NAME§!
This is a question to §COMMUNITY§-Community
for simple approach how to code with Java multiline Strings? 
Like this one.
But it must be simple approach without using of Template-Engine-Frameworks!

Thx for ...
```

Comment: This will work, it will be quite inefficient though, especially as the number of tags grows. It would be better to use a single StringBuilder and scan the String once looking for tokens and replacing them as you find them.

Answer (score 8):

With Java 15+:

```
String title = "Princess";
String name = "Luna";
String community = "Stackoverflow";

String text = """
        Dear %s %s!
        This is a question to %s-Community
        for simple approach how to code with Java multiline Strings?
        """.formatted(title, name, community);
```

Answer (score 2):

One basic way of doing it would be to use `String.format(...)`

Example:

```
String title = "Princess";
String name  = "Celestia";
String community = "Stackoverflow";

String text = String.format(
    "Dear %s %s!%n" +  
    "This is a question to %s-Community%n" + 
    "for simple approach how to code with Java multiline Strings?%n" + 
    "Like this one.%n" + 
    "But it must be simple approach without using of Template-Engine-Frameworks!%n" + 
    "%n" + 
    "Thx for ...", title, name, community);
```

[More info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for this:

```java
String[] args = {"Princess", "Luna", "Stackoverflow"};
String text = MessageFormat.format("Bla bla, {1}, and {2} and {3}", args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Java Resources` in order to achieve it [HERE](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/intl/datamgmt/strings.html)
Or you can keep the current method you're using with different approach like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)

Answer (score 1):

Java 21 (releasing September 2023) is introducing a string templating syntax as a preview feature. This is [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430). A preview feature means that all Java 21 JDKs must include it, but it will be gated behind a compiler flag, and future Java versions may remove or change it. So it will likely be included as a final feature in future Java versions, but there's no guarantee.

With the current version, a template expression is written as a normal string prefixed by `STR.` and contains embedded expressions written like `\{variableName}`.

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Expressions can be written inside of these, like so:

```java
String filePath = "tmp.dat";
File   file     = new File(filePath);
String msg = STR."The file \{filePath} \{file.exists() ? "does" : "does not"} exist";
```

These also work with text blocks.

```java
String title = "My Web Page";
String text  = "Hello, world";
String html = STR."""
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>\{title}</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <p>\{text}</p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """;
```

(All of these examples are from the JEP.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String title = "Princess";
String name  = "Luna";
String community = "Stackoverflow";
String text = String.format("Dear %s %s!\n" +  
            "This is a question to %s-Community\n" + 
            "for simple approach how to code with Java multiline Strings?\n" + 
            "Like this one.\n" + 
            "But it must be simple approach without using of Template-Engine-Frameworks!\n" + 
            "\n" +
            "Thx for ...", title, name, community);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has no built-in support for templating.  Your choices are:

- use an existing templating framework / engine,
- build your own templating framework / engine (or similar), or
- write a lot of "string bashing" code ... like in your question.

You may be able to write the above code a bit more concisely using `String.format(...)`, `MessageFormat` and similar, but they don't get you very far ... unless your templating is very simple.

---

By contrast, some languages have built-in support for string interpolation, "here" documents, or a concise structure building syntax that can be adapted to templating.