# How can I read XML content and put it in a text input box using Selenium?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to store the below xml in a String variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>          
<PublishData>             
<PublishProfile          
PublishMethod="AzureServiceManagementAPI"
Url="https://management.core.windows.net"
ManagementCertificate="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">
<Subscription
  Id="36eccef3-558a-4b-9e14-4efcf57ab86c"
  Name="Enterprise" />
<Subscription
  Id="12501f03-5b8c-448d-a342-24c5f8"
  Name="Development" />
```

and use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ACPSIBDAzure.AccessKey")).sendKeys(/* String Variable */);
```

to pass xml content to a text input box. How can I do this using Java

Comment: You can use a xml parser to parse through the content and get the value from the specified tag.

Comment: I don't want to get the contents just copy and paste the XML code in text box using Java @Vinay

Comment: where is this xml? Is it locally stored on your machine or is it a part the application?

Comment: I have contents of the XML. I can save it in a file in my local or simple paste it in the code. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You put your XML into a String variable. If you do not know how, perhaps this will help: [Java multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)
Then you reference that variable in your next .sendKeys() statement.