# "Illegal line end in string literal" using JSON data in Android Studio

Tags: android, json

I have read many posts but did not help me in solving this problem. Really hope this is not a duplicate question. I have been studying about JSON parsing in Android, and when I copied the below JSON data from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) into Android Studio, it is giving me an error - "illegal line end in string literal"

```
String strJson="
        {            \"Employee\" :[
            {
                \"id\":\"01\",
                \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
            },
            {
                \"id\":\"02\",
                \"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
            },
            {
                \"id\":\"03\",
                \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\",
                \"salary\":\"600000\"
            }
            ]
        }";
```

Please help me to solve this problem, so I can master the JSON parsing technique.

Answer (score 1):

See the post about Java multiple line string

[Java multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string?rq=1)

Use this instead,

```
String strJson = "{" +
            "\"Employee\" :[" +
            "{" +
            " \"id\":\"01\"," +
            "\"name\":\"Gopal Varma\"," +
            "\"salary\":\"500000\"" +
            "}," +
            "{" +
            "\"id\":\"02\"," +
            "\"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\"," +
            "\"salary\":\"500000\"" +
            "}," +
            "{" +
            "\"id\":\"03\"," +
            "\"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\"," +
            "\"salary\":\"600000\"" +
            "}" +
            "]" +
            "}";
```

Comment: Good start! Perhaps mention _why_ they are having the problem, rather than just providing a solution?