# Format Json Strings intellij?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I am developing Java using intellij idea. And I want to assign a json like format to a Java String. But I am tired with escape characters that I have to deal with.

Is there any easy tool to format without escape characters?

Comment: Escape characters have nothing to do with your IDE. These are the rules of Strings in Java being enforced. Rather than hardcoding JSON Strings, you should consider using one of the many JSON libraries available for Java to construct your document, then serialize it to a String.

Comment: Write a JSON file instead of dealing with strings.

Comment: you should be using inject language feature. :))

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use **inject language** feature.

Ex:

```
String myJsonString = "";
```

- Place cursor between " and ".
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  -> Inject language or reference -> select **json** from the dropdown appears,
- Now you have injected json to that String. Again <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> Edit Json Fragment.
- Now you can give your json inside pop-up tool as a normal json, Intellij will convert it as a String with escape characters for you. :))

[image]

Refer [**official documentation**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-language-injections.html) for more info.

Comment: I cannot see `json` in dropdown. Can I somehow add it? I'm using Community Edition of IDEA.

Comment: Now see it. It was unavailable within quotes as argument of function (`..someFunc("{\"jsonHere\"}")`). When I've copied escaped json into assignment (`String t = "here"`), it appears. Thank you!

Comment: How can I share this config with other team members, so they wont have to also pick json?

Comment: Is there a way to reformat this JSON? pressing option+command+L does nothing

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili try Shift+Command+A -> Reformat Code

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is using STS (Spring Tool Suite) and generally Eclipse the escape feature can be enabled by checking the checkbox under:

> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing -> Escape text when pasting into a
>   string literal

after this just define a String and paste the `json` content and the IDE will take care of the escaping.