# Please explain the error in the java code here

Tags: java

Hello i am a noob java programmer.I have written two codes the first one works fin e and there is no error however in the second code there are lots of error.Can someone explain why the white spaces are not acknowleged in the second code.Also is there any other way of writing this code without using System.out.println multiple times?
code1[with errors]

```
 public class letter
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("+----------------------------------------------------+
                       |                                           ###      |
                       |                                           ##       |
                       |                                           #        |
                       |                                                    |
                       |                                                    |
                       |                                                    |
                       |                                                    |
                       |                                 Bill gates         |
                       |                                 Microsoft 1 way    |
                       |                                 Redmond,WA 98603   |
                       |                                                    |
                       +----------------------------------------------------+");
    }
}
```

code2[errorless]

```
  public class Lettertoyourself
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   System.out.println("+----------------------------------------------------+");
   System.out.println("|                                           ###      |");
   System.out.println("|                                           ##       |");
   System.out.println("|                                           #        |");
   System.out.println("|                                                    |");
   System.out.println("|                                                    |");
   System.out.println("|                                                    |");
   System.out.println("|                                                    |");
   System.out.println("|                                 Bill gates         |");
   System.out.println("|                                 Microsoft 1 way    |");
   System.out.println("|                                 Redmond,WA 98603   |");
   System.out.println("|                                                    |");
   System.out.println("+----------------------------------------------------+");
    }
}
```

Comment: Include code as text, not as image(s)

Comment: don't post links to code, post your actual code here, allong with any error(s) or error messages you get

Comment: You'll need to copy and paste the code here, we can't tell from just an image.  Likely you've got a weird character in there somewhere.

Comment: Java doesn't do multi-line strings (yet), see https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/raw-strings/

Comment: Java does not support multiline-strings. (not yet, at least)

Comment: Your "error free code" isn't error-free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string).

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support multi-line strings.

You need to put in the newlines yourself:

```
System.out.println("  line 1\n  line 2\n  line 3");
```

or, if you think it more readable:

```
System.out.println("  line 1\n" +
                   "  line 2\n" +
                   "  line 3");
```

or:

```
System.out.println(
    Stream.of(
        "  line 1",
        "  line 2",
        "  line 3").collect(joining("\n"))));
```

You can replace `"\n"` with `System.lineSeparator()` if you want; but I would only really suggest doing that in the third of the styles shown here, as otherwise it will seriously harm the readability of the code.

Comment: Yet. Hopefully soon.

Comment: You may prefer `System.lineSeparator()` to `\n`.

Comment: @Zabuza you might, but oof, the readability hit.

Comment: Agreed. How about `printf` with `%n` :)

Comment: @Zabuza that's fine provided you don't have anything in the string which would otherwise be interpreted as a format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {


    System.out.println("+--------------------------------------------+"
            + "|                                                     |"
            + "                                                     ");

}
}
```

you just need to add + " " for every line , i dont know what u mean by multip system.println but yes you can store the lines on a String var , and then print all of them using one system.print ln