# Multi line string in Java 17

Tags: java, maven, java-17, java-text-blocks

I am using multi line strings  in java 17.0.2 but have been recieving the following error

```
        String test = """
        {
            "deploymentResourceId": "deployment"
        }
        """;
```

Error:

```
/sparta/input/PackageResource.java:262:25: expecting SEMI, found '"
        {
            "'

2023-10-17 23:31:16.027 UTC [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (verify-style-1) on project : Execution verify-style-1 of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check failed: begin 1253, end 18, length 18 -> [Help 1]
```

Using string builder works fine but i want to use multi line strings

Comment: The error message is not from the Java Compiler but from the checkstyle plugin / from checkstyle. It could be that you are using an old version of the checkstyle plugin (your version is 2.17, the current version is 3.3.0) and / or an old version of checkstyle itself that doesn't yet support the multiline strings that have been added to Java 17. The fix would be to upgrade the checkstyle plugin and the checkstyle version.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Java has support for multiline strings since around Java 15 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/does-java-have-support-for-multiline-strings) and the OPs code is valid Java code for Java 17.

Comment: According to https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/9111 you need at least CheckStyle version 8.36 (and a version of the CheckStyle plugin that supports CheckStyle 8.36)

Comment: The close as duplicate isn't correct - an unescaped quote is valid in multi-line declaration, its just that checkstyle isn't up to date.

Comment: @ThomasKläger your comments would form the basis of a good answer. Hint, hint.

Comment: Please upgrade the maven-checkstyle-plugin versions to most recent version... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is produced by an outdated version of [CheckStyle](https://checkstyle.org/).

According to the CheckStyle ticket [Support for Java 15 Strings](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/9111) you need at least CheckStyle version 8.36 if you want to use [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) / multiline strings together with CheckStyle checks.

The error message (*org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check*) indicates that your project uses the Maven-CheckStyle-Plugin version 2.17 which according to [Maven Checkstyle Plugin Releases History](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/history.html)  by default uses CheckStyle version 6.11.2

You can try to configure your project to use the Maven CheckStyle Plugin 2.17 together with the CheckStyle version 8.36 using the following configuration (source: [Upgrading Checkstyle at Runtime](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html)):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>8.36</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolved my issue .
I am trying to update my text block as below to include some variables 
`String test = """
        {
            "deploymentResourceId": "%s"
        }
        """.formatted(deploymentResourceId); `  but the variable is not getting replaced in the json. do you know how to resolve this? 
i also tried

Comment: I also tried 
`String test = """
        {
            "deploymentResourceId": "$deploymentResourceId"
        }
        """;`

Comment: @pirateking you should open a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` and `checkstyle` resolved the issue:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
      <version>10.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```