# In Java how can i do here docs? Like BASH or PHP we can

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, bash4

How can i do with Java. Here doc like string? Exaple:

```
String java = << \EOF
#This file is written via Java
#You are watching JavaHereDoc
; comments ;
value=abc
etc etc

EOF;
```

System.out.println(java); shows exactly like above. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with large text snippets in Java source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782810/working-with-large-text-snippets-in-java-source)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java (as of 7) doesn't support HERE docs (also known as multiline strings) unfortunately.

If you're trying to accomplish templating, there are a few options:

- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)

These aren't exactly similar to HERE docs in Perl or PHP since the string that describes the template isn't directly in your code; it's usually in a separate file.

There was a [proposal](http://blog.joda.org/2008/01/java-7-multi-line-string-literals_594.html) put forward by Stephen Colebourne as well as a [proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000034.html) via Project Coin, neither of which made it into Java 7, which was a little disappointing. Languages like Groovy and Scala, which also run on the JVM do support multiline strings.

Comment: May be supported by Java 7. I confirm that a dead end in Java 6.

Comment: @Renaud They didn't make it into 7. There was a proposal for it, but it didn't make it in. Hopefully in 8.

Comment: Crazy Java. I have to stick with this then at-least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string/878704#878704

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Arf… Thanks for the precision…

Comment: @Google Yes, unfortunately :( Renaud No worries. I was pretty disappointed that it didn't make it in.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime if you find it useful here's a basic swing application I use to do this for SQL that's embedded into the classes. I find myself using it over and over again so why not share it?

https://github.com/danielbchapman/Swing-String-Escaping-Utility

(a small note, its throw away code since I put it together in a week where I needed to rapidly format queries, I might clean it up at some point)